# Un button que active otro

Tags: php, javascript, botón, scroll, navbar

No se si será posible pero me plantie poner un `button` en mi `header` (es una barra que hace `scroll` con toda la pagina) el cual les permita a los usuarios guardar los datos del formulario que ya lleven cargados (es un formulario largo y de varias hojas y lo pueden cargar en partes). Esto lo hago para que puedan guardar no importa en la parte de la pagina que estén, así no tienen la necesidad de irse hasta el final.

Esta es mi barra de navegación con `scroll`

```
<body style="background-color: #DEDFD6">
   <div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="row flex-items-xs-between menu-1 flex-items-xs-middle" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a data-scroll href="#muniform" class="btn btn-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Datos Generales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a data-scroll href="#asd" class="btn btn-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Tablas</a>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a data-scroll href="#asd" id=guardarmovil" class="btn btn-info" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Guardar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"><form action="eleccion.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="rr" id="rr" value="<?php echo $rr; ?>">
                <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-info" name="cuentacam" id="cuentacam" value="Home"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="php/salir.php" class="btn btn-info">Cerrar Sesión</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
```

Y este es parte de mi formulario como ejemplo:

```
<form action=eleccion.php method="POST" id="muniform">
        <table border="0" style="font-family: italic;" id= "tablass">
          <tr>
           <td>Municipio:</td>
           <td><input list="listaMunicipio2" name="Municipio2" value="<?php echo $fila['municipio'];?>"/><datalist id="listaMunicipio2">
            <option value="25 de Mayo"/>
            <option value="9 de Julio"/>
            <option value="Adolso Alsina"/>
            <option value="Alberti"/>
            <option value="Almirante Brown"/>
            <option value="Arrecifes"/>
            <option value="Avellaneda"/>
            <option value="Ayacucho"/>
            <option value="Azul"/>
            <option value="Bahia Blanca"/>
          </datalist>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Código Municipio:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtCodMun" minlength= "5"maxlength="5" size="9"  value="<?php echo $fila['codmuni'];?>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Año: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtAnio"  minlength="4 "maxlength="4" size="4"  value="<?php echo $fila['ano'];?>"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <?php
        if ($fila['vocalia'] == "A"){

          ?>
          <td>Vocalia: </td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="Vocal" id="v1" value="A"  checked/>A<input type="radio" name="Vocal" value="B" id="v2" />B</td>
          <?php 

        }else {
          ?>
          <td>Vocalia: </td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="Vocal" id="v1" value="A"  />A<input type="radio" name="Vocal" value="B" id="v2"checked/>B</td>
          <?php
        };
        ?>
      </tr>
      </table
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">    <br><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="rr" id="rr" value="<?php echo $rr; ?>">
```

Necesito que se ejecute ese `input` el `btnGuardar` cuando hagan click en el `<a>` que esta arriba con el `id = "guardarmovil"`

```
        <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar" value="Guardar Cambios" class="btn btn-success"/>
</form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El botón que quieres que se pulse cuando haces `click` en otro es también el botón que hace el `submit` del formulario. Sabiendo esto podrías hacer que el botón en cuestión realice también el `submit`.

Para ello podemos usar la función `submit()` de **JQuery**, que envía el formulario que le pasemos en el selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#lanzar_formulario').on('click', function() {
    $('#formulario').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="lanzar_formulario">
  LANZAR FORMULARIO
</button>

<form id="formulario" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

**Solución similar con Javascript Vanilla:**

```html
<button id="lanzar_formulario" onclick="lanzar_formulario()">
  LANZAR FORMULARIO
</button>

<form id="formulario" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>

<script>
  function lanzar_formulario () {
    document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
  }
</script>
```

**Referencia:** [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: <script>
  function lanzar_formulario () {
    document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
  }
</script>con eso agarra todos los elementos del formulario? o tengo q agarrar elemento por elemento y enviar?, donde hiria a el archivo al que lo envio? por ejemplo cargar.php

Comment: Con eso lo que haces es como si le dieses al botón "ENVIAR" del formulario. Se va a enviar el formulario junto con todo los `<input>` que tenga dentro. Y los datos irían a donde tengas marcado en el atributo `action` de tu `<form>`